# How to handle downloads in mobile site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

How does one handle image downloads in a mobi site - using jquery mobile and asp.net mvc 3 and have a requirement to allow a user to download wallpapers to their mobile.

Can you trigger a download or is best to simply simple the image to them and let them handle the saving?

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you can force the download of content on standard browsers by setting headers

```
"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"LicenseAgreement.pdf\""
```

on the return.  This SO shows how to return a PDF file but theoretically, you could do the same with an image.

[How can I present a file for download from an MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730699/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-code-for-pdf-downloads)

However, it is questionable if *every* browser that is supported by jquery mobile would even respect that and give any kind of a save prompt or just open the image in a new window. Give it a shot but test it on iOS, Android, WinPhone 7.5+, and (gagging) Blackberry 6+ and see what happens because they're probably going to all behave a little differently.

Were it me, I'd simply link directly to the image either on the current page or with a target="_blank" and let them save it however they usually save images.