# How to pass Js array object with normal object collection to controller in ajax post 'html' datatype

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the collection of string and array variable which is need to pass controller through ajax post action. for Ex:

```
string str="john";
int temp= 10;
var arrayObj=new Array();
$.ajax({

           type: 'Post',
           url: 'home/controller',
           data: ?, // how to pass all string,int and array object
           datatype: ?, //'html/ or Json' what will need to give?
          success: function (result) {
    }, 
});
```

Anyone could answer my questions?
Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: Which one is it… JavaScript or C#? Are you looking for help on the client or server side part of this? And do you want it to/does it serve HTML, or JSON?

Comment: 1) what does the receiving controller method look like?  2) dataType is the data that jQuery will receive. If you get a partial view back, for example, that should be 'html'. 3) contentType is how you specify what data type the posting data is.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956913/optimal-way-to-forward-data-selected-from-an-actionresult-to-another/19957860?noredirect=1#comment29706828_19957860

Comment: I need to get this ajax request in controller. server side. My question is, 1. Can we pass the js Array object in ajax 'html' datatype method with string or int collection. 2. Or. should we use JSON to pass the js Array object to server. I need the exact JavaScript code to pass this collections in ajax post

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your controller method:

```
var str="john";
var temp= 10;
var arrayObj = [somevar, somevar2];

$.ajax({

           type: 'Post',
           url: 'home/controller',
           data: {nameParameter: str, tempParameter: temp, arrayParameter: arrayObj},               
           contentType: 'text',
          /* dataType:  , depends on what your controller method returns */
          success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

The other option is to use JSON2 library (NuGet).

'data' would now use

```
JSON.stringify({ nameParameter: str, tempParameter: temp, arrayParameter: arrayObj })
```

The contentType should then change to `application/json`

Comment: Thanks, but, I already stored some double value in the array index arrayObj[0]=1.4, arrayObj[1]= 3.6, like that. i need to send string, int and array object collection.

Comment: You can also omit the `contentType` and `dataType` parameters until you have things working.  jQuery can usually infer the types for you.