# Designing data in $.ajax to match server side model definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm running the following AJAX call.

```
var submission = {};
submission.input = [];
submission.input.push({ Id: "{ab684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}" });
submission.input.push({ Id: "{bb684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}" });
$.ajax({
  url: "http://" + "localhost:49642/Controller/Action",
  data: submission
});
```

It works as supposed to and in my controller I can see two elements. However, the *Id* fields is all-zeros. I'm certain I failed to match the definition of the object on the server-side but I'm to annoyed and frustrated right now to generate more suggestions how to shove the data to the service.

The data model is like this.

```
public class Thingy
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Guid> Blobb { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to use different bracket types, apostrophes and such enclosing the guids on client-side. To no avail. What can I have forgotten?!

## Edit

I need to clarify the structural definition of my information object. The controller is set up to receive the following.

```
public ActionResult SelectionStorage(IEnumerable<Stuff> stuff)
{
  Session["Stuff"] = stuff;
  return null;
}
```

The definition of the *Stuff* class is more complex but the following will suffice as a POC.

```
public class Stuff
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Guid> Ids { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<String, decimal> Amounts { get; set; }
}
```

So, on the client, I'm performing the following set up of the submitted data object.

```
var submission = {};
var subIds = [];
subIds.push("{ab684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}");
subIds.push("{bb684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}");
submission.input = [];
submission.input.push({
  Id: "{cb684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}",
  Ids: subIds,
  Amounts: null
});
```

Note that the *Amounts* will differ from *null* but that headache I haven't even got to, yet.

## Edit 2

New try - a simpler approach. In JS I send the following.

```
var stuff = {};
stuff.input = [];
stuff.input.push("{ab684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}");
stuff.input.push("{bb684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}");

$.ajax({
  url: ...,
  data: stuff,
  type: "POST",
  success: ...,
  error: ...
});
```

On recieving end in C# I have this.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(List<String> input) { ... }
```

This gives *null*. I can't see why.

Comment: my understanding is submission will be removed on the controller side since it is just used for passing the data.  So on the controller you should have List<String> input as an input parameter.  You mentioned seeing 2 elements though so I am guessing you have something like that.  Can you post that line from your controller?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simplify the jquery.  With what you have here you don't need the submission.  If you are sending a complex list back to the controller you need to name your variables but since you are just sending a string back you don't need to do that.  Try changing your data to

```
var input = [];
input.push("{ab684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}");
input.push("{bb684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}");
```

then in the ajax call

```
data: input,
```

or

```
data: Json.stringify(input);
```

then on your controller

```
public ActionResult Action(List<String> input){...
```

**Edit:**

try changing your jquery to this:

```
var stuff= {};
stuff.Id = "{cb684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}";
stuff.Ids= [];
stuff.Ids.push("{ab684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}");
stuff.Ids.push("{bb684cb0-a5a4-4158-ac07-adff49c0c30f}");
```

then in your ajax have data: stuff,  or data: Json.stringify(stuff),

Comment: In fact, the structure is a bit more complex than that. Please take a look at my edit and see if you've got something wise to contribute with.   :)

Comment: I made some changes to your jquery and put it in the edit.  Give that a try and let me know.

Comment: I think the second *var* is superfluous in your example. Having removed it, I still can't get it to work. See edit #2, please.

Comment: you are right.  don't need the second var.  looking at your second example you changed the controller.  That should still be what you had in your first edit.  So your first edit controller with my edit jquery (minus the second var)

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I didn't get **that** to work neither so I went with a simple set up, just to see if we can make **this one** work. Can you confirm that given the *List<String> input* version of the controller and my AJAX call works?

Comment: the names and types don't match so it shouldn't work.  Just to test it working try changing the jquery to match what I first answered with here.  That should match the simplified controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41425/discussion-between-matt-bodily-and-konrad-viltersten)