# How To Send List Of Data From View To Controller With Ajax Form in Mvc4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How To Send List Of Data From View To Controller  With Ajax Form In `Mvc4` :
My Model **Sample :**

```
public class Food
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerModel {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public List<Food> ListFoods { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCustomer(CustomerModel model)
    {   
        //Add New Person
        return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
    }
```

My **View :**

[image: View Sample]

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddCustomer", "Resturant", new AjaxOptions
         {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "Success"

         }, new { @id = "frmaddCustomer" }))
{

    <p>
        <label>Customer Name </label>        
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.CH_TextBox("CustomerName").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
    </p>
    <p>
        Food List
    </p>
<table id="FoodList" class="static-table" data-bind='visible: gifts().length > 0'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 250px;">Name</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td />
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: gifts'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CH_TextBox("Food.name").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CH_TextBox("Food.quantity").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
            <td>
                <a id="deleteRow">Delete</a>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


    <button data-bind='click: addGift' type="submit">New Food</button>
    <button data-bind='enable: gifts().length > 0' type="submit">Send Data</button>


}
```

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980232/designing-data-in-ajax-to-match-server-side-model-definition/20004069#20004069

Comment: Thanks .  but I've used @ajax.beginform() and i did not use Jquery.ajax

Comment: The only way I have been able to send a list was go manually build it and send it.  The only way for data to be included in a postback is for it to be included in a for helper (any except display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following method to post data to controller model :

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CH_TextBox("Food[0].name").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CH_TextBox("Food[0].quantity").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
         </td>
        <td>
            <a id="deleteRow">Delete</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CH_TextBox("Food[1].name").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CH_TextBox("Food[1].quantity").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
         </td>
        <td>
            <a id="deleteRow">Delete</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CH_TextBox("Food[2].name").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CH_TextBox("Food[2].quantity").size(TextBoxSize.Medium)
         </td>
        <td>
            <a id="deleteRow">Delete</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

by using this method, my problem was solved. 
Thanks .