# How save model with AJAX and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, xhtml

I'm trying to do a table where I can add a new item, delete and edit a selected row.

After edit or create a new row, when I click on Save button I want to send my model to the controller and update my view.

I'm trying to send model to controller but my code isn't working. Can anyone explain me why and can I solve it?

**My JQuery code:**

```
function saveUpdates(tableId, model) {
showInitialBtns();

transformInputToText();

var modelData = JSON.parse(model);

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "Backoffice/SaveRow",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(modelData),
    success: function () {
       updateTable();
    }
});
```

}

**My view:**

```
    @model IEnumerable<projetoTeste.Model.BackOffice.Car>


<table class="table" id="container">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th rowspan="2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Owner)
            </th>
            <th colspan="4">
                Other data
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateRegiste)
            </th>
            <th colspan="2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateBuy)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model)
    </tbody>
</table>


<div id="initialButtons" style="display: block">
    <p>
        <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="enable">
            Add new row</button>
        <button type="button" class="disable" id="btEdit">
            Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="disable" id="btDelete">
            Delete</button>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="btnsEditing" style="display: none">
    <p>
        <button id="btSaveEdition" type="button" class="enable" onclick="saveUpdates('container','@(Model)')">
            Save</button>
        <button id="btCancelEdition" type="button" class="enable">
            Cancel</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

**My controller:**

```
public void SaveRow(ICollection<AnatomicLocation> item)
{ 
   //some code
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the model, the controller and what error message you are receiving?

Comment: I update my question with that information. I don't get any error message. I'm doing `alert("test");` after almost every line in my jquery to know where is the problem and it stops in `var modelData = JSON.parse(model);`

Comment: What is `modelData` after `JSON.parse()`? Try `alert(modelData);` after that line.

Comment: It tried that and I don't get anything. Most of my jquery code I got online on some examples

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980232/designing-data-in-ajax-to-match-server-side-model-definition/20004069#20004069

Comment: I don't know why but `Json.stringify` don't work and I have a complet Model and not a specific string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some answers:

1. I can just append that new row to the table and submit all table
   after, like this:

   ```
   $.get(newRowUrl + rowSelectedId, function(data) {
        $("#" + tableId + " tbody").append(data);    
   });
   ```

   And note that it is essential to define the correct name of each
   element of the new row in the table because we are talking about a
   collection of data. For example:

   ```
   @{
        string modelFieldInitialName = "Car[" + Model.Id + "].";
        string modelFieldInitialId = "Car_" + Model.Id + "_"; 
   } 
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Id", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Id" })
   ```
2. Or, we can search the row items and submit them like this:

   ```
   var selectedOption = $("#" + tableId + " tbody tr#" + rowSelectedId).serialize();

   $.ajax({
      url: newRowUrl + rowSelectedId,
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      data: selectedOption,
      success: function () { },                            
      error:function () { },
   });
   ```