# Open pdf file by Ajax call in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a link in my MVC that by clicking that link it open up the pdf file. I like to use ajax call for opening the pdf so keep the page that had the link with all the info and on top of that open the pdf. Right now when the pdf is opened the page with the link is existed but there is not showing any date in it.

What I have now in my controller is:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public void openPdf(string name)
    {

        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"].ToString() + name + ".pdf";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);

    }
```

And in my view :

```
@Html.ActionLink("PDF", "openPdf", "Home", new { @name = item.Application_Filename },null)
```

Comment: Process.Start would open the PDF file on the server. You need to return the PDF as a FileResult or a binary stream.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730699/how-can-i-present-a-file-for-download-from-an-mvc-controller